# UILabel animating frame change disregarding delay

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I have a UILabel that I show / hide. I want to show the label, pause for a few seconds and hide it. This code ISN'T working. It removes the view as soon as the animation finished (instantly)

```
-(void) show
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5f delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn  animations:^{

                    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 64.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44.0f);
                    self.frame = newFrame;

    }                completion:^(BOOL finished){

                            [self hideAndRemove];

    }];

}

-(void) hideAndRemove
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5f delay:2.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn  animations:^{

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 64.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 0.0f);
        self.frame = frame;

    }                completion:^(BOOL finished){

        // nothing

    }];
}
```

However, if I try some other animation on the frame, the delay works and the frame change is animated:

```
-(void) show
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5f delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn  animations:^{

                    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 64.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44.0f);
                    self.frame = newFrame;

    }                completion:^(BOOL finished){

                            [self hideAndRemove];

    }];

}

-(void) hideAndRemove
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5f delay:2.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn  animations:^{

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 64.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 250.0f);
        self.frame = frame;

    }                completion:^(BOOL finished){

        // nothing

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem might be, but I think it comes from the frame height who shouldn't be set to 0.

Why not using [UILabel setAlpha:0] to hide your label, and [UILabel setAlpha:1] to show it back ? It seems cleaner than changing its frame height to 0, and it animates nicely.

Comment: But the animations work to grow the frame. Just not to hide it. I'd like to shrink the frame if possible.